# It there an order-preserving mapping?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

When I thought whether there is an order-preserving mapping which is also a bijection between two partially ordered sets that have the same cardinality, I got the the answer no.
That's because I found a counter-example, that is **there is an infinite descending subsequence in the integer set but not in the natural number set**

So my question is 
**if I have two partially ordered sets that have the same cardinality and both don't have the greatest element or the least element, can I find a order-preserving mapping which is also a bijection between the two sets?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Neither $\Bbb Q$ nor $\Bbb Z$ have a greatest or lowest element. But one is dense, while the other is discrete.

Your next question, then, is about density, or so. There it's a bit more complicated, one can state that if both partial orders are linear and dense *everywhere*, and without minimum or maximum, then they are indeed isomorphic. But otherwise, one can be clever, take two disjoint copies of $\Bbb Q$, or three, or countably many. Take the finite subsets of $\omega$ ordered by inclusion and replace each one with a copy of $\Bbb Q$, or those which have an even number of elements with copies of $\Bbb Q$, and the odd ones with a copy of $\Bbb Z$, or so on.

We can make **very** complicated partial orders, even if they are all countable. It is generally very hard for two partial orders of the same cardinality to be isomorphic. And you need quite a few limitations.

Some positive results would be:

1. Well-orders are unique up to isomorphism, but their "discernable traits" run out fairly quickly.
2. As a consequence, orders which can be partitioned into a well-order and a reversed well-order will also satisfy (at least in thinkable cases) uniqueness up to isomorphism.
3. The rational numbers are unique up to isomorphism.
4. The partial order given by the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ under inclusion is unique, and so is the one given by finite and co-finite subsets.

But by mixing and matching a bunch of them, you can create a great many number of non-isomorphic partial orders. So just going one property at a time is not a good strategy.

Comment: What does "dense everywhere" mean and what do you mean by saying that a given linear order is unique up to isomorphism?

Comment: Dense everywhere means that it is dense, between any two different points there is a third. I wrote everywhere to make the distinction between just "a copy of $\Bbb Q$", since otherwise we can take $(0,1)\cup\{2,3\}\cup(4,5)\cap\Bbb Q$ as a countable linear order which is "almost dense" except two points, $2$ and $3$. As for "unique up to isomorphism" means exactly that. I'm not sure what's confusing about it. It means that given some property, any two linear orders satisfying it will be isomorphic.

Comment: But it's not true in general that two dense linear orders without endpoints of the same cardinality are isomorphic. That's what I understand you're saying in the second sentence in the second paragraph. Unless you are assuming the sets are countable... are you?

Comment: You did notice that the question was about countable orders, right? (Or at least that my answer has been only about countable partial orders.)

Comment: Ok. About the other doubt, which properties that imply uniqueness are implied when saying for example that finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ ordered under inclusion are unique?  Like for example if you said that countable dense linear orders without endpoints are unique, or that the first order theory of $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ is $\omega$-categorical, I'd get it, but just saying that the rational numbers are unique gets a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Anguepa, sometimes these properties are second-order properties (most of the time they are). For example $\Bbb N$ with the usual $\leq$ is the unique linear order without a maximum that every proper initial segment of it is finite. $\rm Fin(\Bbb N)$ under $\subseteq$ is the unique partial order which looks like the atomic countable Boolean algebra's "finite" part. Etc. So it's not that the theory of something is $\omega$-categorical, but rather that the second-order is $\omega$-categorical, or even just categorical.

Comment: I don't know many theories, can you give me a hint of proving that if both countable partial orders are linear and dense everywhere without minimum or maximum then they are isomorphic? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Zero: That is a theorem of Cantor. It's not obvious at all. The key point is that given two finite subsets of the same cardinality (one from each order) there is an order isomorphism between the finite subsets, such that given any point in one of the linear orders we can add it to the finite set and find a suitable point in the other one which can also be added such that the isomorphism can be extended (e.g. you add a point smaller than all your $n$ points, you can find one in the other linear order). Then you enumerate both orders and construct the isomorphism by recursion.

Comment: @Zero Theorem 3 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~scanlon/225af13lectures/20132609Lec9.pdf).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I got it, then I know why you emphasize "countable" by you hint.Thank you! I enjoy this wonderful solution